# Change background color of ListView Items if MATCH found (Android ListView)

Tags: android, listview, arraylist

I have two List ArrayList which have some string values. Also, I have a ListView and an ArrayAdapter. The data given to the ArrayAdapter is coming from one of the ArrayList.

---

What I want to achive is : Compare both the arrayLists and if two elements present in the arrayLists are same, Then when the ListView is generated, the background for the listView item for which a match was found should be of different color.

---

I tried using listview.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.Blue) but it doesnt works. It is giving me as **java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference** on the same line.
If there is any better way to do this then post it in your answers.

```
 private List<String> forexInstruments;
 private ListView forexListView;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

String[]  temp = new String[]{
                "'" + "EURCAD" + "'",
                "'" + "USDGPY" + "'",
                "'" + "AUDUSD" + "'",
                "'" + "USDCHF" + "'",
                "'" + "EURGPY" + "'",
                "'" + "6B 03-16" + "'",
                "'" + "6E 03-16" + "'",
                "'" + "CL 03-16" + "'",
                "'" + "ZB 09-16" + "'"    
        };
    //1st Array List
    selectedGlobalInstruments = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(temp));

    //2nd Array List
    forexInstruments = new ArrayList<>();
    forexInstruments.add("EURCAD");
    forexInstruments.add("USDGPY");
    forexInstruments.add("AUDUSD");
    forexInstruments.add("EURGBP");
    forexInstruments.add("USDJPY");
    forexInstruments.add("GBPUSD");
    forexInstruments.add("EURGPY");
    forexInstruments.add("USDCHF");


    forexListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    final ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new    ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item_layout,R.id.list_item_instrument_textview,forexInstruments);
    forexListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    //Comparing both the ArrayLists. If two elements ar eqaul then change background color
    for(int j=0; j< selectedGlobalInstruments.size(); j++) {
        String tempA = selectedGlobalInstruments.get(j);
        Log.v("Selcted",selectedGlobalInstruments.get(j));
        for(int i=0; i < forexListView.getCount(); i++)
        {
            String instrumentList = "'" + forexListView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString()+ "'";
            Log.v("forexListview",instrumentList);
            if (tempA.equals(instrumentList)) {
                Log.v("Satisfied",instrumentList);
                forexListView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

list_item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_item_instrument_textview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp">
</TextView>
```

---

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.shubhamhpcs.listviesttes.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: First check if it is going in your if condition or not by printing something.

Comment: @Drv The if condition is now getting satisfied. But now I am getting an error. Can you please look again.

Comment: Can you add the code from `DataTable` please?

Comment: Even post your layout code of listview.

Comment: Not of listitem, post code of your activity_main.xml

Comment: @IulianPopescu Sorry Sir, my bad. The project contains only one activity. I have made the changes in the code

Comment: @Drv Posted the layout code

Comment: @Drv posted activity_main.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, an `Activity` shouldn't take care how an item from `ListView` is displayed, letting this job for an adapter (you're doing this in `onCreate` without having the rows for `ListView` created, resulting in a crash).
So what I would do is to create a class that has 2 fields: `String value` where you have your actual data to be displayed and a `boolean hasBackground` that indicates if that item should be displayed with a custom background or not. That class should look like this:

```
public class ListItem {
  public String value;
  public boolean hasBackground = false;

  public ListItem(String value, boolean background) {
    this.value = value;
    this.hasBackground = background;
  }
}
```

Then I would make the `forexInstruments` to have elements of type `ListItem`. I would add the elements like this: `forexInstruments.add(getDefaultItem("USDGPY"));`, where `getDefaultItem` is method that returns `ListItem` with background set to `false`.

```
private ListItem getDefaultItem(String value) {
    return new ListItem(value, false);
}
```

After the list is initialised it have to be updated, so I created a method to find the common elements between those 2 lists, setting the `hasBackground` field to `true` for those elements.

```
private void updateCommonElements() {
    for (int j = 0; j < selectedGlobalInstruments.size(); j++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < forexInstruments.size(); i++) {
        String instrumentList = "'" + forexInstruments.get(i).value + "'";
        if (selectedGlobalInstruments.get(j).equals(instrumentList)) {
          forexInstruments.get(i).hasBackground = true;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

In the end, the `onCreate` would look like this:

```
forexInstruments = new ArrayList<>();
forexInstruments.add(getDefaultItem("USDGPY"));
forexInstruments.add(getDefaultItem("AUDUSD"));
forexInstruments.add(getDefaultItem("EURGBP"));
forexInstruments.add(getDefaultItem("USDJPY"));
forexInstruments.add(getDefaultItem("GBPUSD"));
forexInstruments.add(getDefaultItem("EURGPY"));
forexInstruments.add(getDefaultItem("USDCHF"));

updateCommonElements();

forexListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1);
adapter.addAll(forexInstruments);
forexListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

where `MyAdapter` is a class extending `ArrayAdapter`, being responsible for colouring the background of a row or not.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem> {
  int res = 0;
  int textRes = 0;

  public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
    res = resource;
    textRes = textViewResourceId;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(res, parent, false);
    }
    ListItem item = getItem(position);
    if (item.hasBackground) {
      convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    } else {
      convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(textRes);
    textView.setText(item.value);
    return convertView;
  }
}
```

And this is the final result in my simulator:
[image: screenshot]

Note: I used some Android default layouts, but they can be changed to your layouts in a few seconds.

Comment: I am getting error as: ------- 1) forexInstruments.add(getDefaultItem("USDGPY")); In this line : list cannot be applied to com.project.new.ListItem.-----2) adapter.addAll(forexInstruments); addAll cannot resolve method -------3) forexInstruments.get(i).hasBackground = true; cannot resolve symbol hasBackground ##########I would like to thank you for all the trouble that you went through. But if you can check and tell where I went wrong it would be great. I am new to android development.

Comment: Let's fix the problems: 1) did you changed the type of `forexInstruments`? it should be something like this `private List<ListItem> forexInstruments;`  2) did you created the adapter as I did and make sure that it extends `ArrayAdapter` and no 3) should be related to the first one. Try this and let me know how it goes

Comment: I didnt do the private List<ListItem> forexInstruments; part. Got the output.THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! You made my day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify your adapter for the change :

```
arrrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Didn't helped. I suggest you to look at the code once more.I have made changes

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to getItem of list when it is not yet completely set.Please check if below helps:

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter =null;
String[]  temp = new String[]{
            "'" + "EURCAD" + "'",
            "'" + "USDGPY" + "'",
            "'" + "AUDUSD" + "'",
            "'" + "USDCHF" + "'",
            "'" + "EURGPY" + "'",
            "'" + "6B 03-16" + "'",
            "'" + "6E 03-16" + "'",
            "'" + "CL 03-16" + "'",
            "'" + "ZB 09-16" + "'"    
    };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

init();


forexInstruments.add("EURCAD");
forexInstruments.add("USDGPY");
forexInstruments.add("AUDUSD");
forexInstruments.add("EURGBP");
forexInstruments.add("USDJPY");
forexInstruments.add("GBPUSD");
forexInstruments.add("EURGPY");
forexInstruments.add("USDCHF");

arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

//Comparing both the ArrayLists. If two elements ar eqaul then change background color
checkSameItems();

}     

private void init(){
    //1st Array List
    selectedGlobalInstruments = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(temp));

    //2nd Array List
    forexInstruments = new ArrayList<>();
    forexListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    arrayAdapter = new    ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item_layout,R.id.list_item_instrument_textview,forexInstruments);
    forexListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}

private void checkSameTimes(){
     for(int j=0; j< selectedGlobalInstruments.size(); j++) {
    String tempA = selectedGlobalInstruments.get(j);
    Log.v("Selcted",selectedGlobalInstruments.get(j));
    for(int i=0; i < forexListView.getCount(); i++)
    {
        String instrumentList = "'" + forexListView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString()+ "'";
        Log.v("forexListview",instrumentList);
        if (tempA.equals(instrumentList)) {
            Log.v("Satisfied",instrumentList);
            forexListView.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your strings are both different, they wont be ever equal.
Since your

```
selectedGlobalInstruments.get(0) = 'EURCAD';
```

which you are initializing as : `"'" + "EURCAD" + "'",`

while:

`forexInstruments.get(0) = EURCAD ;`

There is a difference of `'` in both the strings so they wont be equal.

Comment: I have made the changes in the code and also edited the code. Still the background color doesn't change.